# Drupal Global: Combine Fields Filter

Tags: php, drupal-7, drupal-views

The site is built with a Drupal 7.26 minimal installation.

I'm attempting to utilize the Global: Combine Fields Filter within views to query within multiple fields for the same values entered in the form that is created.

I'm noticing different operators exist when utilizing the Global: Combine Fields Filter as opposed to the other filters I can setup.

Specifically, it appears as if there is no 'is between' operator to provide a range of values to search between.

Can anyone verify if this is the case, and if not, why is it failing to display the 'is between' operator?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, it may be to late for you but I answer this for anyone searching for a solution.

First you have to create a custom module.

In your `mymodule.module` file:

```
<?php 
/**
 * Implements hook_views_api()
 */
function custom_views_filter_views_api() {
  return array(
    'api' => 3,
    'path' => drupal_get_path('module', 'MYMODULE'),
  );
}
```

Then you have to create a `mymodule.views.inc` file. In this file I used the following hook: [hook_views_query_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_query_alter/7)

```
/**
 * Implements hook_views_query_alter(&$view, &$query)
 */
function MYMODULE_views_query_alter(&$view, &$query) {

  if ( $view->name == 'MYVIEWNAME' && $view->current_display == 'MYVIEWDISPLAY' ) {
    $conditions = &$query->where[1]['conditions'];

    foreach($conditions as $k => $q) {
      if( $q['operator'] == 'formula' && preg_match('/SOME-STRING/', $q['field']) ) {
     //the preg_match here is just to be sure I'm altering the right WHERE condition so I can use the Global filter again in this display if needed. 

        $conditions[$k]['field'] = ":views_combine BETWEEN field_data_field_NAME1.field_NAME1_value AND field_data_field_NAME2.field_NAME2_value";
        //original "field": "CONCAT_WS(' ', field_data_field_NAME1.field_NAME1_value, ' ', field_data_field_NAME2.field_NAME2_value) LIKE :views_combine"

      }
    }
    //you can delete your "variable by reference"
    unset($conditions);
  }
}
```

And happily for me it worked! :-). Just to say my values where numeric. So to be tested with other types of values.

Hope it helps.